# How to exclude few rows from displaying? "DISTINCT" - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I was trying to select only the last Message from a certain someone. here's the query I came up with

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", ContactID, Msgs.DateS
FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Msgs ON Contacts.ContactID IN (Msgs.SenderID, Msgs.RecieverID)
WHERE AccountID = 1 ORDER BY Msgs.DateS ASC;
```

But it still shows me other messages, I want only one to show up. here's the resulting table:

[Picture showing the resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RplQ9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(m.MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", ContactID, m.DateS
FROM Contacts c
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1  Msgs.MessageID, Msgs.DateS 
        FROM Msgs 
        WHERE c.ContactID IN (SenderID, RecieverID)
        ORDER BY DateS DESC
    ) m
WHERE AccountID = 1;
```

Comment: Then only one row will show up, I want multiple rows, each one represents the last Message someone sent.

Comment: I've fixed my answer

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005 or above

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 WITH TIES ISNULL(MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", ContactID, Msgs.DateS
FROM 
    Contacts 
    LEFT JOIN Msgs ON Contacts.ContactID IN (Msgs.SenderID, Msgs.RecieverID)
WHERE 
    AccountID = 1 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY Msgs.DateS DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just fine, but, would you bother elaborate this for me? how does it work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, try this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", ContactID, max(m.DateS)
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN Msgs m ON c.ContactID IN (m.SenderID, m.RecieverID)
WHERE AccountID = 1 Group By MessageID,c.ContactID 
ORDER BY m.DateS ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DISTINCT` , you need an `aggregate function`

```
SELECT ISNULL(MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", ContactID, MAX(Msgs.DateS)
FROM Contacts 
LEFT JOIN Msgs ON Contacts.ContactID IN (Msgs.SenderID, Msgs.RecieverID) 
WHERE AccountID = 1 
GROUP BY MessageID, ContactID
ORDER BY Msgs.DateS ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the "last" message, use `top 1`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(m.MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", c.ContactID, m.DateS
FROM Contacts c LEFT JOIN
     Msgs m
     ON c.ContactID IN (m.SenderID, m.RecieverID)
WHERE AccountID = 1
ORDER BY Msgs.DateS DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT  ISNULL(MessageID, -1) AS "MessageID", ContactID, Msgs.DateS,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Msgs.DateS DESC ) AS Seq
        FROM Contacts 
        LEFT JOIN Msgs ON Contacts.ContactID IN (Msgs.SenderID, Msgs.RecieverID)
) AS t WHERE t.seq=1 AND AccountID = 1 
ORDER BY Msgs.DateS ASC;
```